# Nydus worm behavior

Tags: starcraft-2

In what order do units exit a nydus worm? FIFO (First In First Out) or LIFO (Last In First Out)? Is it the same from the nydus network as it is with the nydus worm?

If you have multiple nydus worms exiting at the same time, do the units alternate between them?

Comment: if memory serves correctly you can only have units exit from one nydus worm at any given time, so you shouldn't be able to use a 'mass exit' command on more than one worm.

Comment: @Ender you can unload units from multiple nydus networks and worms simultaneously. Unloading simultaneously from, say, 3 worms at the same time appears to approximately triple the unload speed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I did some testing, units exit FIFO no matter if you use the Nydus Network or the Nydus Worm.

When using multiple exits it will alternate between them, so if you have 2 zerglings, a roach, 2 more zergling and one more roach enter the network and you then command 3 Worms to unload all you will get 2 zerglings from 2 of the worms and 2 roaches from the third.

I made a video showing this: